# Yii2 redirect with timer

Tags: redirect, timer, notifications, yii2, logout

I want to log the user out after changing his password, but also want to show them the notification that it has changed.

So in order to do this, I'd like to use a redirect command with a timer of 2-5 seconds.. Sadly I couldn't find it anywhere.

Any help?!

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just show this notification on the login form?

Comment: It is not a proper practice to show the notification this way. First you should log out the user and redirect him to login page with the above notification.

Comment: And you could use a flash message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do as follows. Logout user then send him to login page.

```
public function actionPasswordChangeFunction()
{
    ...........

    Yii::$app->user->logout();
    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('reLog', 'Password Changed Successfully.');
    return $this->redirect(['login_form_path']);
}
```

On your login page:

```
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('reLog'); ?>
```

Comment: Eventho I didn't ask for this, I am using your method simply because it's better.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a redirect using javascript. 
For this you need to include the following javascript in the view you generate. Example below would wait 5 seconds before redirecting to the redirectURI you have passed from php

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.location.replace("<?php echo $redirectURI ?>");
    }, 5000); 
</script>
```

Comment: This was the correct answer to my question, yet the other method was better than mine. Still +1'd! Thank you